# How to hide content when clicked checkbox from different components in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
//inputtwo.vue

<template>
  <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />one</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "inputtwo",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
//maincontent.vue

<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="!checked">
      <p>Text is visible</p>
    </div>
    <common />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "maincontent",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    hidecont() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
//inputone.vue

<template>
  <div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" />one</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "inputone",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

How to hide content of checkbox from different components in Vuejs

I have three components called inputone(contains checkbox with v-model),inputtwo  (contains checkbox with v-model),maincontent.(having some content and logic), So when user click on checkboxes from either one checckbox(one,two). i schould hide the content.

Codesanfdbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-wx9uo?file=/src/components/maincontent/maincontent.vue

reference code:- https://codepen.io/dhanunjayt/pen/mdBeVMK

Comment: You want to hide Text is visible content when either of the checkboxes is selected?

Comment: Yes exactly. but in my case I have checkboxes in two different components. When user select either of the checkboxes. the content "Text is visible" should hide.

Comment: @HumayonZafar Can I achieve it like this ----- https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-wx9uo?file=/src/components/maincontent/maincontent.vue 

(Or) any alternative way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually not syncing the data between components. The main content checked never changes. You have to communicate data between parent and child components or this won't work. And try using reusable components like instead of creating inputone and inputtwo for same checkbox create a generic checkbox component and pass props to it. It is a good practice and keeps the codebase more manageable in the longer run.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <maincontent :showContent="showContent" />
    <inputcheckbox text="one" v-model="checkedOne" />
    <inputcheckbox text="two" v-model="checkedTwo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import maincontent from "./components/maincontent/maincontent.vue";
import inputcheckbox from "./components/a/inputcheckbox.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    maincontent,
    inputcheckbox,
  },
  computed: {
    showContent() {
      return !(this.checkedOne || this.checkedTwo);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      checkedOne: false,
      checkedTwo: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

checkbox component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      :checked="value"
      @change="$emit('input', $event.target.checked)"
    />
    {{ text }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "inputcheckbox",
  props: ["value", "text"],
};
</script>
```

Content:

```
  <template>
    <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="showContent">
            <p>Text is visible</p>
    </div>
  </template>

    <script>
       export default {
           name: "maincontent",
           props: ["showContent"]
         }
    </script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/confident-buck-kith5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Hope this helps and you can learn about passing data between parent and child components in Vue documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Thanks I got the logic. But in my case, I have two components where checkbox are coming while looping the array values from two different components. I tried to place the checkboxes in two components namely inputone, inputtwo. But i am getting error.

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-wx9uo?file=/src/components/maincontent/maincontent.vue

Comment: Tried to  create inputone and inputtwo, and take individual component for checkbox. By following your code. But not working :( Not sure why

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please share it.

Comment: Getting error as :- Unknown custom element: <maincontent> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Here is the code :- https://codesandbox.io/embed/crimson-fog-wx9uo?file=/src/components/maincontent/maincontent.vue

Comment: You are getting errors because you have not imported the maincontent in inputone and inputtwo components and are trying to use them in the templates. Secondly, there is no inputcheckbox component in your code and the logic is also not correct.

Comment: Now, I imported the maincontent in inputone and inputtwo components.   Now i getting new error as Unknown custom element: <inputcheckbox> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: If possible, Can you please correct me.  https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fog-wx9uo?from-embed=&file=/src/components/a/inputone.vue

Comment: Hey, @sundar you are not using the components correctly. Try learning the basics first like how and where to use the components in templates and different ways of binding data between them. This will help you a lot in the longer run. Here is the codepen with two inputs: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-liskov-kh51t?file=/src/components/maincontent/maincontent.vue

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) to store and maintain the state of the checkbox. If you're not familiar with Vuex, it's a reactive datastore. The information in the datastore is accessible across your entire application.